# How to search for lines not containing some text?

Tags: search, interactive

In a large file, I want to find which lines which do not contain a given string, `grep -v` basically.

<kbd>M-x `grep`</kbd> helps, but it forces to protect special characters, is not interactive nor incremental, and doesn't let me edit the file at matches.

How to find such lines ?

Comment: Relatedly on SO : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640492/emacs-inverse-search `M-x flush-lines` comes closest, but I don't want to remove the lines, just search them out. `hide-lines.el` seems nice but extraneous.

Comment: M-x grep seems the easiest way. You can edit the matches using wgrep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is simple if you use [**Icicles**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles).

You can use [**Icicles** search](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Search_Commands%2c_Overview) to search contexts of any kind, including lines. For searching lines the command is `icicle-occur`, bound to `C-c '`.

During **Icicles** search you type text (it can be a regexp, substring, etc.) as a search pattern to match, and the contexts that match that pattern are retained as candidates to visit/show.  In other words, your search is narrowed to contexts (e.g. lines) that match what you type. And this is dynamic: change the text in the minibuffer to another pattern, and the matching contexts change immediately.

During **Icicles** search (and during completion more generally), you can use **`C-~`** anytime to narrow *subtract* the current matching contexts from the previous set of contexts (e.g. the original domain of contexts, such as all lines in the buffer). That is, `C-~` **complements** the current set of matches.  Which is what you asked for.

---

Peripherally related to your question, you can also use **`C-M-~`** (same key, but with *Meta-* added) to complement, not the current search candidates, but the domain of **contexts** used from then on.  This is useless if the contexts (areas to be searched) are all of the lines in the buffer, but it is quite *useful for contexts that are not contiguous*.

For example, there are **Icicles** search commands to search various THINGs (e.g., different types of sexps) as contexts, and these are not necessarily contiguous.  When you hit `C-M-~` during search, instead of searching the contexts you define, **Icicles** [searches the **non-contexts**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Search_Commands%2c_Overview#SearchOutsideContexts). That is, `C-M-~` changes to searching the *complement* of the set of contexts.

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest:

> is not interactive nor incremental

You can use emacs re-builder `M-x regexp-builder` for interactive/incremental search.

> I want to find which lines which do not contain a given string,

Using "complemented char set" syntax `[^...]` is the only thing I have for doing something close to to `grep -v`

> and doesn't let me edit the file at matches.

Once you're satisfied with the regex you built inside the regexp-builder, you can `M-x reb-copy` to copy it, then paste it in, `M-x query-replace-regexp` for finding and replacing operation

Answer (score 0):

```
(defun my/grep-v(regex)(interactive)
   (while
       (and (not (eobp))                       ; not end of buffer
            (re-search-forward regex (line-end-position) t)) ; search this line     
     (forward-line 1)))                      ; skip to next line
```

`(my/grep-v ":CAL:")` 
will skip to first line without ":CAL:"
(or to the end of the buffer)